# jQuery submit form after effect is complete?

Tags: jquery, queue

I'm trying to use jQuery's `queue()` to `show()` a div prior to submitting a form.  However my current code just immediately submits the form before the `show()` effect even starts.  BTW `#savebutton` is not a submit element, just an image with this click event.

```
$("#savebutton").click(function () {
    $("#saving").queue(function()
    {
        $("#saving").show("slow");
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});
```

How can I make sure the `show()` completes before submitting?

Thanks for any advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL, had the queue assigned to the wrong id.  Corrected code works:

```
$("#savebutton").click(function () {
    $("#savebutton").queue(function()
    {
        $("#saving").show("slow");
        $("#form1").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: `submit` doesn't queue, it will execute straight away with the animation going on in the background.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [show(speed, callback)](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show#speedcallback) function:

```
$('#savebutton').click(function () {
    $('#saving').show('slow', function() {
        $('#form1').submit();
    });
});
```